# How to make sense out of this: Ergodic theorem for Markov chains

Tags: probability, measure-theory, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

We had the ergodic theorem for Markov chains, stating that: For a state space $S \subset \mathbb{N}$ and all functions $f \in L^1$ (meaning that $\sum_{s \in S} |f(s)|\pi(s) < \infty$) and an irreducible positive recurrent Markov chain $(X_n)$ with $X_n:\Omega \rightarrow S$, we have that 
$$\frac{1}{n+1} \sum_{i=0}^{n}f(X_i) \rightarrow  E_{\pi}(f) $$ almost sure, where $\pi$ is the stationary distribution and for any starting distribution we could imagine.

As I received a lot of protest, I want to be more precise about my problem.
After we proved this theorem our lecturer continued with a remark that I did not understand:
First, he told us that for any indicator function $\chi_A$, where $A \subset S$, we have $\frac{1}{n+1} \sum_{i=0}^n \chi_A(X_i) \rightarrow \pi(A)$ almost sure.

Now, we concluded from this that for the starting distribution $P_{X_0} :=\delta_x$  for any $x \in S$ we have that $P_{X_i} \rightarrow \pi$ in distribution. $P_{X_i}$ is the pushforward measure, such that $P_{X_i} (s) = P(X_i=s)$ for $s \in S$.

I did not understand this, but maybe anybody here has an idea: how this could follow/ what our lecturer missed / what could be meant here?

Comment: I suspect this wants you to use $f(X)$ as an indicator function that is 1 if $X$ is a certain state, and 0 else.

Comment: However, the statement of the ergodic result is not clear.  It would be helpful to define set $S$ (it must be a set of real numbers).  Also, the set $S$ must connect in some way with $f()$ being in $L1$.  What if $S = \{n^n | n \in \{1, 2, 3, \ldots\}\}$?

Comment: It is also not clear what you mean by $P_{X_i}$.  If this is supposed to mean $Pr[X_i=s]$ for $s \in S$, then this is not true, as an aperiodic assumption would be needed for these probabilities to converge.  If it means the fraction of time, then the indicator function argument works.

Comment: @Michael sorry, you may be also right about the 'fraction of time' although I don't understand what you exactly mean by that. The thing is that this was a note at the end of a large chapter and therefore lacked rigourousness. could you explain how $\frac{1}{n+1}\sum_i {\chi_x({X_i})} \rightarrow \int_Sf(x)d \pi(x)$ implies weak convergence?

Comment: @user180097 As Michael notes, you *cannot* conclude weak convergence unless you make additional assumptions.

Comment: You need to clarify what $f \in L1$ means.  I would assume that means $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |f(x)|dx < \infty$, but that does not make sense in this context.  I'm guessing you really mean something like $\sum_{s\in S} \pi(s)|f(s)| < \infty$.

Comment: Also, the result you mention seems to have no connection with probabilities converging (only time averages converging).  Consider a (periodic) 2-state Markov chain with states 0, 1, and transition probabilities $P_{01}=P_{10}=1$. This is irreducible and positive recurrent, but $Pr[X_i=1|X_0=1]$ oscillates and does not have a limit as $i\rightarrow \infty$.  Of course, $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{i=0}^nPr[X_i=1|X_0=1]=1/2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer: It does **not** follow. I don't know what your lecturer meant or said, but you **cannot** draw this conclusion, as Michael's example shows.

Let $(X_n)$ be a Markov chain with state space $\{0,1\}$ and transition matrix $P=\pmatrix{0&1\cr 1&0}$. The unique invariant distribution is $\pi=(1/2,1/2)$, 
but $\mathbb{P}_0(X_n=0)=(-1)^n$ does **not** converge to $\pi(0)=1/2$.

What is missing is the *additional assumption* that the Markov chain is *aperiodic*.
In that case, what your lecturer said is true.

Comment: I see, then I will have to ask him, what he wanted to tell us.